# Only returning Callback is not a function

Tags: javascript

Having a real difficult time with callbacks. I have a function that will take an image, run it through a method to determine the mime type of the image file. I would like to take that mime type and set the response headers and send the file.

```
.get(function(req,res){
    var fileName = req.params.filename;
    var UPLOAD_PATH = "__dirname + '/../uploads/images/'";

    function getFileType(fileType, callback){
      magic.detectFile(UPLOAD_PATH + fileName, function(err, fileType) 
    {
        if (err) return callback(err); 
        callback(null, fileType); 
      });
    }

    var fileType = getFileType();
    console.log('Get file type', fileType);

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', fileType)
    fs.createReadStream(path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, req.params.filename)).pipe(res)
   });
```

Would like to

1. Run the function to get the file type
2. Set the file type
3. Return that file type into the `res.setHeader()`

Right now I'm running into an error `TypeError: callback is not a function`

Comment: You aren't passing any parameter in `var fileType = getFileType();`. You need to pass a function. Try passing a like `var fileType = getFileType("someType", function(arg) {})`;

Comment: Can you please explain why a function should be passed as an argument?

Comment: Think I found what you are talking about here https://youtu.be/qN0dkXj7jc0?t=6m16s

Trying to piece this together and if that's what you are referring too feel like that's progress in learning

Comment: Yes, Callbacks are nothing but function stored as a variable. So you can pass them around and call whenever you want. Here in your case, passing the function as a variable part was missing. It's alright, you will understand more as you write more javascript. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Define your call back fucntion. Otherwise it will not be defined.

```
.get(function(req,res){
    var fileName = req.params.filename;
    var UPLOAD_PATH = "__dirname + '/../uploads/images/'";

function getFileType(fileType, callback){
  magic.detectFile(UPLOAD_PATH + fileName, function(err, fileType) 
{
    if (err) return callback(err); 
    callback(null, fileType); 
  });
}
//Your Call back function defenition
function callback(x, type ){
 // Show him the file type.
}

var fileType = getFileType();
console.log('Get file type', fileType);

res.setHeader('Content-Type', fileType)
fs.createReadStream(path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, req.params.filename)).pipe(res)
```

});

Comment: Trying to comprehend what you posted and it really isn't clicking. It looks like the callback declaration is out of scope of the get function. And declaring it like you have here renders the same results. I've moved it in scope but and that runs but feels like it negates the need for a callback

Comment: like this the function callback will be available atleast inside .get's callback function. defining JS function like this is self hosting and will have the needed scope to be defines where it is used.